# How to correctly compare host names

Tags: c#, comparison, host

I have a few host names that I need to compare and tell if they represent the same host, for example:

```
localhost
127.0.0.1
machineName
```

What is the most reliable way to do it in C#? For now I'm doing that like:

```
    private bool CompareHosts(string host1, string host2) 
    {
            UriBuilder builder1 = new UriBuilder(); 
            builder1.Host = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host1)[0].ToString();  
            var uri1 = builder1.Uri; 

            UriBuilder builder2 = new UriBuilder(); 
            builder2.Host = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host2)[0].ToString(); 
            var uri2 = builder2.Uri; 

            return Uri.Compare(uri1, uri2, UriComponents.Host, 
                   UriFormat.Unescaped, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
    }
```

I've not included error handling for host addresses array, but I'm not sure what to do if it will return more then one address, does it mean that they will represent different machines? Is there any better way to compare them? I need to check that those hosts refer to the same machine.

Comment: Don't forget `::1` and `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` too ;p

Comment: It is correct that a single hostname can have multiple IP addresses - consider the case of a PC with 5 network cards...

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110703 for confirmation.

Comment: @RB - Less rare that 5 network cards would just be that multiple IP addresses have been assigned to a single connection.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is no, if you have a machine with 2 network cards (for example), there is no sure way of knowing that it comes from the same machine, since it is really 2 distinct network elements.

However, you can handle some special cases like the localhost versus 127.0.0.1 you mentioned.

When you get multiple IPs from the DNS query it usually means the machines ARE NOT the same since this technique is commonly used for load balancing between different machines.

In the past there were many hacking techniques to discover if 2 ips are the same machines, in some cases you could get the internal time of the machine or if it opened ports in a consecutive order you could also use that. But I strongly advise not going that way. There is probably a better of achieving your goal without doing this check (e.g. if you have a web application you can easily use cookies for this). Again, need more context to help.

Comment: Hi @idanzalz, its not a web application, its a desktop application where the user can enter a couple of hosts (ip or machineName) for different servers and I need to analyse them and say if they are on the same machine or not

Comment: what do you mean by "analyze". do they have something installed you can talk to? do you know the operating systems? If it's a windows machine you probably can get the machine name via netbios. Can you control/assume anything on the configuration of the machine?

Comment: The only assumption I can make is that these machines have windows installed on them. Depending on whether two hosts represent the same machine I need to make sure I provide the same configuration for them. But I don't check what software is installed on machines.

Comment: Do they access you from internet or lan?

Comment: I believe thats what System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses also does - it can resolve netbios name. Anyway I can't force people to use only netbios names (and it is not supported on vista, windows7). But the question is - is it enough just to check if I have any matches in returned ip addresses, or maybe I need to do it another way like try to resolve ip and compare returned names (I hope I will not end up comparing dns name with netbios name)?

Comment: I'm not sure the Dns will give you netbios necessarily. check out [this post](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/03/11/getting-a-machine%E2%80%99s-netbios-domain-name-in-csharp/) about getting the netBios name

Comment: Can you please explain why do I need to use netbios name instead of dns name

Comment: I am suggesting to try both since you might not have the names in the local dns and dns may be different for different network adapters. netbios is more the name of the OS, which seems to be more fitted to what you need